# Xcode does not automatically create app id on developer portal

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, itunes-app

As indicated in the title, `Xcode` is not being able to automatically create app Id and provisioning profile for an app i’m developing. I have checked the “*Automatically manage signing*” option but on the developer portal i can’t see any app id or provisioning profile matching the provided bundle identifier.

The problem arises only if I select, in the “team” selection, my developer account . For example, by using my enterprise account, the “waiting to repair” message is shown in Xcode and i can see the new app id created in the enterprise account portal.

If I change the bundle identifier and I select again my developer account, nothing happens, no errors and no warnings. I’m able to install the application on a device and all seems to be good. However, in my developer portal I still do not see the *app id* and *provisioning profile* so i can’t send the application to `iTunes` connect in order to submit to the `Apple store`.

Moreover, trying with other apps, all is ok even using my developer account.

I searched on line but i can’t be able to find a similar problem, are there any particular settings that are preventing the automatic Xcode app id creation to work for my app?

**EDIT**

it seems it’s not a problem related to the particular app. In fact I tried to create a new application fromo scratch and i have the same problem. I still do not have the problem on old apps (already uploaded on itunes connect) but i have the problem on all the newly created apps. Is that a problem with my developer certificate?

**EDIT 2**

I noticed that for all the newly created applications the App ID is set to: " * " (see image below). In my old apps the App ID and iOS Team Provisioning Profile are not equals to " * ". I have also deleted the wildcard id from my developer portal but the problem still remain.

[image: Xcode appId error]

Comment: Any resolution for this? I also have this problem.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I had a similar problem and i solved with a workaround. I have enabled push notifications in the "capabilities" tab (i.e, adding them to the entitlements), in this way the app id and provisioning profile have been correctly generated on the developer portal. Later, I have disabled push notifications (not needed in my project).

It's only a workaround, hope it helps

Comment: Brilliant.  Worked great.  App id got registered immediately.

Comment: great, nice hack :)

Comment: Splendid! Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: definitely apple should solve this bug, your solution is awesome, thanks X 1000.

Comment: Thanks for this tip! It works, but then another problem happens: after enabling push notifications, it is not possible to disable them. Even after disabling in both developer center and Xcode I still can see push notification in capabilities list (info icon near Xcode Managed Profile)

Comment: Worked like a charm, surreal world of apple! thanks

Comment: where is the capabilities tab? you mean "Signing & Capabilities" ?

Comment: @ronpaleum yes, in the newer versions of XCode the tab is named "Signing & Capabilities". You have to add capability in this tab by tapping the "+ Capability" button on the upper left corner

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat related: I played around with Apples provisioning profiles in a desperate attempt of trying to wrap my head around their signing nightmare. In the process I deleted all the app ids from [apple.developer](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/) that Xcode had automatically generated.

Afterwards I couldn't get Xcode to regenerate the app ids and I didn't wanted to manually create them, so what I had to do was to delete the automatically generated provisioning profiles from `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/`.